# Android: Programatically added EditText - content goes off screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a label and an input field (`EditText`), that I add programatically to a `TableLayout`.  When I enter text that is longer than the input field, the values go offscreen.  How should I fix this, so that I can see what I'm typing, and can also scroll back to the beginning of the input field?

Example when typing `A-Z1-9`:

[image]

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.myapplication.DocumentActivity">

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/document_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</TableLayout>
```

Code:

```
fun showDocument() {
    var documentLayout: TableLayout = findViewById(R.id.document_layout)
    val row = TableRow(documentLayout.context)

    val inputField = EditText(row.context)
    inputField.setScroller(Scroller(documentLayout.context))
    inputField.maxLines = 1
    inputField.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true
    inputField.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = true
    inputField.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
    inputField.overScrollMode = EditText.OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS

    val label = TextView(row.context)
    label.text = "Label"
    label.labelFor = inputField.id

    row.addView(label)
    row.addView(inputField)

    documentLayout.addView(row)
}
```

Comment: What you expect from this code `inputField.maxLines = 1` ?

Comment: 1) Avoid adding Views dynamically if possible. It's bad practice in general as it makes your UI less maintainable, and it increases possibility for error.
2) Try setting the ellipsize mode to 'marquee' for that EditText (search: `ellipsize TextView`. Also see how it behaves when you place it from XML instead from Java/Kotlin

Comment: You can also use `this` as Context, as you're probably in an Activity there

Comment: Before adding views you should set constraints. In your case `TableLayoutConstraints`: `inputField.setConstraints(Component, new TableLayoutConstraints(.....))`

Comment: @Ibrahim `inputField.maxLines = 1` I was hoping would restrict the input field to 1 line and would enable scrolling horizontally.

Comment: @milosmns Thanks for the recommendations.  I've tried setting `ellipsize` to `marque`, but got an error that EditText cannot have `ellipsize` set to this value.

Comment: @NorthernPoet There doesn't seem to be a class called `TableLayoutConstraints`.

Comment: @Jerry, Sorry, my mistake about TableLayoutConstraints. Simply use `android:layout_weight="1"` for children.

Comment: If I remove all the setters for `inputField` and only set `inputField.setEms(10)` and `inputField.setSingleLine()`, the behavior is what I'm after, but the width is hard-coded.  Any ideas how I can can set the `inputField` to stretch to the end of the row?

Comment: @Jerry singleLine is deprecated unfortunately, but people still use it because maxLines has various issues. Did you try a combination of layout weight set to 1 and singleLine? That might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to implement this using a vertical `LinearLayout` component as the main placeholder, and then populating horizontal `LinearLayout` components with the `ViewText` and `EditText` components.

My complete implementation that generates 15 'labels' and 'input fields' is:

**Layout XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.myapplication.DocumentActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
android:id="@+id/activity_document">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/document_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Code:**

```
    var documentLayout: LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.document_layout)

    var lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
    lp.leftMargin = 8
    lp.rightMargin = 8

    for (i in 0..15) {
        var linearLayout = LinearLayout(this)
        linearLayout.id = View.generateViewId()
        linearLayout.layoutParams = lp

        val inputField = EditText(this)
        inputField.id = View.generateViewId()
        inputField.setSingleLine()
        inputField.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT, 1f)

        val label = TextView(this)
        label.id = View.generateViewId()
        label.text = "Label $i"
        label.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT, 0f)

        linearLayout.addView(label)
        linearLayout.addView(inputField)
        documentLayout.addView(linearLayout)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you have to remove this line

```
inputField.maxLines = 1
```

and also use `LayoutParams`

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
inputField.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope it will help you  :)

Comment: It's a requirement to have one line only and fully fill the screen horizontally. This removes the requirement and works around the issue, and will probably still cause it if overflown verrically.